# Detect if a string is a link w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to detect if a target string is a link or not. If yes, i need to grab the URL and place it into a var, do something with the string a (run through a plugin to truncate), and then wrap new string into the link again. I think i should be able to accomplish this with jQuery, right?

```
<div class="item">some string</div>
<div class="item">another string</div>
<div class="item"><a href="myUrl.php">linked string</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want something like:

```
$('.item > a').each(function(){
    var url = this.href;

    //do your stuff

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you it will find all links in the class off item

```
    $(".item a").each(function(index){

var url = $(this).attr("href");
url = url+"hello";
$(this).attr("href", url);

});
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/gcLU4/

Comment: don't need to wrap `this` with jquery function, `this.href` works fine.

Comment: While true, it can produce a different result. Using attr(), you get the exact string in the htef attribute. this.hre will always give you the absolute path.